# Extension of scalars for a $k$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, schemes

Let $k$ be a field and let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a $k$-scheme. Let $K/k$ be a field extension. I don't quite understand what is mean by the scheme $X_K$, formed by "extension of scalars."

One thing seems clear to me - if $U \subset X$ is an open subset, and $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the $k$-algebra of sections on $U$, then the sections of $X_K$ on $U$ should be $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \otimes_k K$.

My question  is, what exactly is $X_K$, that is, what is the underlying topological space? Is it just the same as the underlying topological space $X$, and just the structure sheaf changes? If not, how can I describe $X_K$?

If $X$ has an open cover by affine schemes $X_i = \operatorname{spec} A_i$, then the corresponding open subset of $X_K$ should ber $\operatorname{spec} (A_i \otimes_k K)$, so probably $X$ and $X_K$ can't have the same underlying topological space.

Comment: They don't have the same underlying topological space - for example take $X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$. As a topological space this is a point. If you extend by scalars to $\mathbb{C}$, you have $X_{\mathbb{C}} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2+1)$, which is two points.

Comment: In general it would help if you work out the affine description first. If you stick with fin.gen. k-algebras (varieties), say $X=\operatorname{Spec}k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$, where $f_i \in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, then $X_K = \operatorname{Spec} K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$. Essentially you're taking the same equations but looking at the locus they cut out in $\mathbb{A}^n_K$ rather than $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

Comment: On affine charts it looks like a tensor product. Do you know another construction that looks like tensor product on affine charts ?

Answer (score 1):

When $K = \overline{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$, and $X$ is locally of finite type over $k$, it may be easier to consider what is $X$ in terms of $X_{\overline{k}}$, rather than the other way around.  The projection $X_{\overline{k}} \rightarrow X$ is a surjective open and closed map, in particular a quotient map.  On the level of topological spaces, $X$ is obtained from $X_{\overline{k}}$ by glueing together points which are in the same $\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{k}/k)$ orbit.

This is explained in Mumford's red book, and is also in Stacks project somewhere.  There is probably a similar description for when $K$ is an arbitrary algebraic extension of $k$, but I can't immediately find a reference.